# Could not find schema file in network drive (e.g. \\UNC_Path\myfile.xsd) when executing SSIS package under sql server Catalogs

Tags: ssis

My package is used to extract data from xml to database.

When I execute the package in visual studio, it completes all task successfully.

But when I deployed the package to server and execute the package under Integration Services Catalogs, it fails to get the xml schema file on a network drive with error message: 'The file "\\UNC_Path\myfile.xsd" was not found'.

Thanks

Comment: The account that is running the SSIS package does not have access to `\\server\share\myfile.xsd`

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and that fixed it (thanks billinkc)

The account that is running the SSIS package does not have access to \\UNC_Path\myfile.xsd